# C# - Selecting multiple items in a ListBox and converting into a comma separated string in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm building a GUI to update a database with values from a listbox. I've already connected to the server and database, and I have it putting information into the correct columns. I just can't get it to display the multiple values that I select. I'm pretty new to this.

```
string colors = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var items in listboxColor.SelectedItems)
{
 sb.Append(listboxColor.SelectedItem + ", ");
} 
colors = sb.ToString();
```

---

This is an example:

```
Example ListBox (** is the selected item)
**Red**
Blue
**Green**
Yellow
Orange
**Purple**
--------------------------
Output:
Red, Red, Red
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Output:
Red, Green, Purple
```

Thank you! If you need more info, let me know please.

Comment: Take a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line in the foreach.

You are using `listboxColor.SelectedItem` that gets the selected item with focus (so always the same).

Here is the correct code :

```
string colors = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var currentItem in lbOwner.SelectedItems)
{
 sb.Append(currentItem + ", ");
} 
colors = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

In fact, "string.Join" is much simpler.

```
string.Join(", ", listboxColor.SelectedItems.Cast<object>())
```

It is complicated to use "foreach" due to the commas.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool isFollowing = false;
foreach (var item in listboxColor.SelectedItems)
{
    if (isFollowing)
    {
        sb.Append(", ");
    }
    else
    {
        isFollowing = true;
    }

    sb.Append(item);
}
string colors = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I agree it needs less code with `string.Join`, but less "complex" being the scene, I could not bet on that. First, just saying, I always prefer changing the less possible code when, as it seems to be, a beginner asks a question. Second, when I use a loop like these, I usually append the "separator" before the "item" and after, if the "colors" variable is not empty, I remove the first separator occurrence which requires only one condition validation instead of N.

Comment: Therefore, I post two answers together. Beginner needs to fix his code; but at the same time learns to write readable code efficiently. Anyway, removing the first separator is indeed a great idea, thank you.

Comment: I agree that they need to learn, but we can never presume of their learning curve and where they are. I already taught to beginners and that's why I prefer : one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just `string` as listbox item you could do this.

```
string colors = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in lbOwner.SelectedItems)
{
    sb.Append(item + ", ");
} 
colors = sb.ToString();
```

in case if `ListBoxItem` is an object you need to cast it respective type and get the property/field required.

```
ex..
foreach (object item in lbOwner.SelectedItems)
{
    sb.Append((item as type1).Prop1 + ", ");
}
```